# convert JSON to CSV file using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to fetch data from JSON file and store it into csv file. This JSON file has nesting and multiple records for same key value i.e.`value`.

Source File:

I tried below code which flattens the json file, but i am unable to get to required csv format.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def flatten_json(nested_json):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out


response = json.loads(data)
df=pd.Series(flatten_json(response)).to_frame()
print(df)
```

Below is the output which i get after executing above code:

```
                                                          0
data_Value_strt_0_col1                                 John
data_Value_strt_0_col2                                David
data_Value_strt_0_col3                                 Lisa
data_Value_strt_0_col4                                 None
data_Value_strt_0_col5                                 None
data_Value_strt_0_data_byValue_0_col3                   dev
data_Value_strt_0_data_byValue_0_col6                  None
data_Value_strt_0_data_byValue_0_col1                  None
data_Value_strt_0_data_byValue_0_data_value_201...    02.22
data_Value_strt_0_data_byValue_0_data_value_2020-1    12.32
data_Value_strt_1_col1                                  Ram
data_Value_strt_1_col2                                Shyam
data_Value_strt_1_col3                              Kishore
data_Value_strt_1_col4                                 None
data_Value_strt_1_col5                                 None
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_0_col3                   prd
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_0_col6                  None
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_0_col1                  None
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_0_data_value_2020-3    12.87
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_1_col3               dev-prd
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_1_col6                  None
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_1_col1                  None
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_1_data_value_201...     3.39
data_Value_strt_1_data_byValue_1_data_value_201...     9.24
```

I am unable to get to above format using above code since there is nesting and multiple values for Key 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for the data you've provided. It's possible that this may not work if there is more data you haven't shown, and the format changes:

```
import json
import csv

data = ...

info = json.loads(data)["data"]["Value"]["strt"]

fieldnames = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Col_4", "Col_5", "Val_Col3", "Val_Col6", "Val_Col1", "Val_Year", "Val_Month", "Value"]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    for d1 in info:
        for d2 in d1["data"]["byValue"]:
            for key, value in d2["data"]["value"].items():
                year, month = key.split("-")
                row = [d1["col1"], d1["col2"], d1["col3"], d1["col4"], d1["col5"], d2["col3"], d2["col6"], d2["col1"], year, month, value]
                writer.writerow(row)
```

This will write to a CSV file in the format you specified. `None` values are written to the file as empty strings by the `csv.writer` object. If you want to introduce whitespace into the CSV file, so that the delimiters line up, you may have to make some changes.